# How to return multiple elements in a list?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I am using CherryPy and I need to print on my page one bi-dimensional list. Example:

```
exx = [['Michael', 'Jordan'], ['Magic', 'Johnson']]
```

So if I do this:

```
for i in range(len(exx)):
    return (f"{exx[i][0]} {exx[i][1]}")
```

it prints just the first element cause I'm using 'return'. How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: You can also `yield` things. But in general, you have to learn more about Python, this question has next to nothing to do with CherryPy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
exx = [['Michael', 'Jordan'], ['Magic', 'Johnson']]
def return_all():
    return [f"{exx[i][0]} {exx[i][1]}" for i in range(len(exx))]

return_all()
```

```
Out[28]: ['Michael Jordan', 'Magic Johnson']
```

Or as a function if you want to reuse it:

```py
def return_all(elements):
    return [f"{elements[i][0]} {elements[i][1]}" for i in range(len(elements))]

return_all(exx)
```

Comment: in this way, it prints on the terminal and not on the webpage :/

Comment: ok, I didn't even know you could use cycles in the return statement. Do I need square brackets? and for when I use the .format way of printing? thanks!

Comment: Yes the square brackets are needed.

Comment: While this answer helps the question author, for it to be useful to others @ SO, please add the explanation.